# SQL - MariaDB : SQL Error 1292 Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value

Tags: sql, concatenation, mysql-error-1292

after few search with my buddy G, I found a lot of solution, but no one corresponds to my situation.
Quick explanation :
I am currently trying to create a "test table" which will receive 4 millions lines per day. That's around 48 lines/seconds.

To simulate this situation, I want to create a default number for my "LotNumber" column, which will being create based on hour and minutes.
Exemple : all the lines created at 9AM and 45min will have the following "LotNumber" : W11409:451

a.k.a **W114+HH:MM+1**

So, my default column value is :

```
concat(cast('W114' as char charset utf8mb4) + left(cast(curtime() as char charset utf8mb4),5) + cast('1' as char charset utf8mb4))
```

And hell yes, that's barbaric.
My "LotNumber" column is **VARCHAR**,

When I create a single line, HeidiSQL send error message 1292.

I am new to SQL, and I have no idea where my error is.

Comment: If you use `concat` function, use `,` to concatenate the data, not `+ `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code works, just separate the data elements by `,` instead of `+`

```
select concat(
  cast('W114' as char charset utf8mb4),
  left(cast(curtime() as char charset utf8mb4),5),
  cast('1' as char charset utf8mb4)
  )
```

You can test on this [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.6&fiddle=268621f570cb02a4d5439bbb62aeafa2)

Comment: Hey James, thanks for answering quickly. 
I changed my code, but when I add a line, I have this new error : 1292, Truncated Incorrect Time Value : ''
I try with/without "select" you add.

Maybe because I am in Default value ?

Comment: Can you replicate your query in some Maria Db on db<>fiddle. As I shared you, the query changing just those little points works.

Comment: Ok, well, that's work when I use a query from console, and since beginning I am creating line by my own, with right click... and this doesn't work well.

Thanks you for your useful help.